# Expandable & Collapsable UITableView sections from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Hi I have a table with information from a json with addresses, I manage to sort them by neighborhood when pressing a button, I would like to create expandable & collapsable sections with the neighborhoods with the same button.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] init];
}
NSString *cellName = [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
NSString *cellState = [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath:@"desc"];
NSString *cellTodo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", cellState, cellName];
[[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 11.0]];
cell.textLabel.text = cellTodo;
return cell;
}


- (IBAction)PorBarrio:(id)sender {
NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"desc" ascending:YES];
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
[myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Check Apple sample code [Table View Animations and Gestures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) for collapsible table view

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442697/how-to-create-an-accordion-with-uitableview-under-a-uitableview

Comment: I just started a [GitHub project](https://github.com/i2097i/SRExpandableTableView) for an iOS expandable UITableView called SRExpandableTableView. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

My personal vote is for `SLExpandableTableView`.  You can find it here on [GitHub](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView).

It's brilliantly easy to use but not well documented; currently there are no examples.  It basically acts as an extension on the regular `UITableView` class, and works great with storyboard prototypes / custom look & feel.  So you don't have to do a ton of re-work if you've already got a UITableView going.

It took me a bit of figuring out on exactly how to implement the `expandingCellForSection:` method - here is mine so that it makes it a bit easier for others:

```
- (UITableViewCell<UIExpandingTableViewCell> *)tableView:(SLExpandableTableView *)tableView expandingCellForSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"amenitysectioncell_immediate";
    AmenitySectionTableViewCell *cell = (AmenitySectionTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AmenitySectionTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdientifier];
    }

    cell.sectionTitle.text = @"blah blah";

    return cell;
}
```

The trick is to subclass `UITableViewCell` for your sections cells:

```
@interface AmenitySectionTableViewCell : UITableViewCell<UIExpandingTableViewCell>  

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *sectionTitle; 

@end
```

Enjoy!

Comment: thank you @capikaw. please share your basic working example!  i continue to crash :(.  there still doesn't seem to be a buildable example posted on github.

Comment: It doesn't work if you have a UIViewController (and a UITableView inside) instead of UITableViewController

Comment: It certainly does work. I did it with UIViewController following [this forum](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView/issues/14)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

*Use uiTableView delegate method "viewForHeaderInSection" and return a custom UIView.

*Add a UIButton as subview with action "expandable:(id)sender" check the sender id as section number and reload the table view.

Check this Link :

http://iostechnotips.blogspot.in/2014/05/expandable-uitableview.html

example :

```
 -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection(NSInteger)section {
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,2 , tableView.frame.size.width, 20)];

    UIButton * headerButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
    [headerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(expandeble:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [headerButton setTag:section];
    [headerButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d",section] forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
    [view addSubview:headerButton];
    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    return view;
}

-(IBAction)expandeble:(id)sender{
    UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    [self exapand:(int)myButton.tag];
}

-(void)exapand:(int)tag{
    if (senctionIndex != tag) {
    senctionIndex=tag;
    [_expandableTable reloadData];
}}
```