# How to generate the accordion view dynamically in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add view & Header dynamically to an (objective-c) accordion view as my data come through array.

I have to make the view according to the size of array.

Comment: This might point you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607722/accordion-table-cell-for-expand-and-collapse-ios

Answer (score 0):

There's no "accordion view" in iOS.

You can accomplish something like this using a UITableView and adding in/deleting rows as the user interacts with the visible rows. You should start by taking a look at [the relevant section in Apple's Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1).