# Nested Expandable UITableView from Plist in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

Hi is it possible to use plist to create a expandable table or view in ios?

Here's the plist file and the control type means

0 = Switch

1 = TextField

[image: pList]

can I iterate the plist to create a expandable table view? and the output should be this. And if the switch is off all the sub parent of the parent will collapse. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in Advance :D
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to save data, how come you want to use the plist?

Comment: No I'll jsut output it so that if I have modification I can easily modify it in the plist

Comment: have you tried using NSUserDefaults?

Comment: hmmm my problem is how can I turn the plist file into an expandable table... my sample output is just static and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Of course, but `UITableView` only have one level, you should arrange subView in `contentView` of `UITableViewCell` according to your plist.

Comment: si it means that Inside a tableview there's another tableview. Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

Let's start from basic idea. I'll focus on expand/collapse functionality, ignoring cell types (switches, textfields, whatever). Table view hierarchy is limited with section level and row level. The requirement is to implement any number of nested levels. But we could indent cells using `indentationLevel` property. Table view would consist of one section with expanded (filtered) cells with level information provided. Therefore, goal is *to transform deep plist hierarchy to flat one* which is easier to manipulate when populating table view.

**The structure of a plist node.**

Node contains following properties:

- name (cell title)
- level (indentation level, hardcoded in plist for simplicity)
- collapsed (wether node is collapsed, changed in response of user interaction)
- children (child nodes in hierarchy)

[image: example of plist hierarchy]

Root element *must* be a dictionary, if you use `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` for plist loading. To keep the order of top level nodes unchanged we use array as a root container.

**Data structure**

Plist hierarchy is represented by `NSMutableDictionary` (mutability is required because we will change `collapsed` property). Table view flat hierarchy is represented by `NSMutableArray` (stay tuned).

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableDictionary *_model;
    NSMutableArray *_items;
}
@end
```

**Transform plist hierarchy to flat one**

Possible solution is to iterate over all nodes, choose expanded only and add them to a flat array. It could be achieved recursively:

```
- (void)reloadExpandedItems
{
    for (NSDictionary *item in _model[@"items"]) {
        [_items addObject:item];
        [self reloadExpandedItemsForItem:item];
    }
}

- (void)reloadExpandedItemsForItem:(NSDictionary*)item
{
    if ([item[@"collapsed"] boolValue]) {
        return;
    }

    for (NSDictionary *child in item[@"children"]) {
        [_items addObject:child];
        [self reloadExpandedItemsForItem:child];
    }

    return;
}
```

**Populate table view**

We need to set indentation level and respond to user interaction (collapse/expand) cells.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [_items[indexPath.row][@"level"] integerValue];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *item = _items[indexPath.row];
    item[@"collapsed"] = @(![item[@"collapsed"] boolValue]);  // inverse bool value

    [self reloadItems];
}

- (void)reloadItems
{
    [_items removeAllObjects];
    [self reloadExpandedItems];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

`reloadItems` retransforms plist hierarchy with new changes. If you want to animate changes you need extra logic for inserting/deleting expanded/collapsed cells.

Comment: thankyou for that vokilam I'll update you as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

[look this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442697/how-to-create-an-accordion-with-uitableview-under-a-uitableview). 
long story short - there no option for standart UITableView class to make it expandable like .plist . you must implement this functionality by your own, or use [this example](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a sample project that uses data from a plist and populates it using expandable sections in a tableView.  Here's the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

This kind of nested TableView can be easily achieved by a very nice Github library [RATreeView](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView.)

Hope this will help.