# How to make accordian(toggle) in IOS on button click

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working at a project in iOS. In my table view I have a list of questions and answers. When the user clicks on the first question, the answer for that question should be displayed, and if I click on `+` symbol the answer should be shown, and if I click on `-` symbol it should be hidden.

Comment: Please show us the code that is giving you trouble, and we'll be glad to point out the areas that may be giving you trouble.

Comment: Have you already looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442697/how-to-create-an-accordion-with-uitableview-under-a-uitableview