# How to recreate the Explore Menu on the Apple App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

The Explore menu in the Apple App Store allows you to make a selection from a UITableView and then it segues to a new view while showing the previous selection at the top of the screen.  It's the best example of mobile breadcrumbs I've ever seen. Here's what it looks like in action:

[image]

On this screen I click "Consumer Products" and that shows me the next screen.  Without taking me out of the view.

[image]

You're able to press on any of the breadcrumbs and segue back to that view.

Can you please show me in Objective-C, how you would achieve a segue like this?
(The most important part of the segue is the breadcrumb functionality at the top of the screen.)

Thanks!

Comment: It is a great UI, agreed! However, I believe this is a duplicate question.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442697/how-to-create-an-accordion-with-uitableview-under-a-uitableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob, I've made very simple project, but hope it will give you an idea how you can achieve such effect

[BreadCrumbsTable](https://github.com/romaHerman/BreadCrumbsLikeTable)

Comment: thanks for the help! This works for what the transition would look like at the end.  I'm wondering how to do the custom animated transition before you get to this point.