# Expandable tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

How to create this view for dynamic data in ios with checkboxed and radio button i searched it from many websites but didn't find. Please sugest me any reference or any solution.
[image]

Comment: see this [M13Checkbox library](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox)

Comment: actually i want to create a new dynamic number cell on selection of that cell with check boxed and other data etc.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442697/how-to-create-an-accordion-with-uitableview-under-a-uitableview)

Comment: what does this question have to do with cocos2d ?

Comment: no only with objective c...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key is how to change content and height of a cell.

When user tap a cell, you need to change content of cell and add more views. After that, you need to set new row height without reload tableview. Here is a post about how to dynamic table view row height http://candycode.io/dynamic-uitableview-height-for-downloaded-images/.

Comment: actually i want to create a new dynamic number cell on selection of that cell with check boxed and other data etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at [HVTableView](http://github.com/innovian/HVTableView)

> This is a subclass of UITableView with expand/collapse feature that
>   comes useful in many scenarios.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question.